# How to set args using Spring Camel Lib in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

Working with SpringBoot, Java 11.

In application.properties i want to configure: `camel.component.rabbitmq.args`

Documentation by camel using rabbitmq: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/rabbitmq-component.html#_message_body

Note: I'm not asking about rabbit, just the configuration in application.

Error i have received trying to configure by my way:

```
application.properties
camel.component.rabbitmq.args={arg.queue.x-message-ttl=3600000}
```

Error:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'camel.component.rabbitmq.args' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>:

    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
```

How is the correct way by example? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `application.properties`, the proper syntax for a component option of type `Map` is `componentOptionName[mapKey]=mapValue` so in your case it would be:

```
camel.component.rabbitmq.args[queue.x-message-ttl]=3600000
```